# How can I upgrade Apache Server version 2.4.39 to 2.4.49 running on Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: apache, upgrade, windows-server-2008

I am currently running Apache Server version 2.4.39 on Windows Server 2008 R2. After launching a vulnerability scan on this server, it shows me this version is vulnerable and I have to upgrade my Apache server to 2.4.49 (vulnerability reference CVE-2021-39275), I'm wondering what steps I should follow to succeed in this upgrade since it's a production critical server. I'm relatively new to Apache so could you please provide me with some assistance.

Thank you in advance!